# Subspace of a Hilbert space with a distinct inner product

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

I don't really know where to begin with the following question:

Let $ (H_0, \langle \cdot \rangle_0)$ be a closed subspace of $ (H, \langle \cdot \rangle )$ such that norms induced by $ \langle \cdot \rangle, \langle \cdot \rangle_0 $ are equivalent in $ H_0 $. I'm trying to prove that for all $ h \in H $ there exists  a unique $ h_0 \in H $ such that $ \forall_{x \in H_0} \langle x,h \rangle = \langle x, h_0 \rangle_0 $

Uniqueness is rather an easy excercise, yet I don't really have any clue what theorem might be useful. The definition of all those notions doesn't seem really helpful to me.

I'd appreciate some help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$x\mapsto\langle x, h\rangle$ is a continous linear functional on $H_0$, therefore, if $H_0, \langle, \rangle_0$ is a Hilbert space, this follows from a well known theorem of Riesz.

(See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz_representation_theorem)

Comment: So it looks like the assumption about the norm equivalence is just to make sure that $ \langle h_0, \cdot \rangle $ is a continuous functional, right?

Comment: @Jytug You also need $H_0$ to be complete w.r.t $\langle, \rangle_0$, otherwise the Riesz theorem does not apply. For two norms equivalence allows you to conclude this in this situation because of homogeneity of norms , i.e. $|\lambda x| = |\lambda| |x|$ for real (or complex) $\lambda$. (For arbitrary metrics equivalence need not preserve completeness).